# .innerHTML() - compare two approaches (javascript basics)

Tags: javascript, function

I am starting to learn JavaScript and have been using w3schools as my resource. As a new kid on the block I would like to ask a humble and simple question. In layman's terms - What is the difference between:

**this code**

```
function myFunction() { 
    return "Hello World"
}
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = myFunction();
```

and **that code**

```
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World!";
}
myFunction();
```

**Reason I am asking is:**
I am doing some exercises and I got the end result correctly by doing **this code** but then when I clicked "show answer" the code shown is **that code** which is different from mine.

In addition to my question - which one is practical and which one is best for what situation?

---

reference exercise [link](http://www.w3schools.com/js/exercise.asp?filename=exercise_functions5).

Comment: In the end they do the same thing. In different context on how/when they would be called might result in different things.

Comment: *"I am starting to learn JavaScript and have been using w3schools as my resource."* I'd strongly recommend using [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/javascript) instead. And various books and blogs. Not w3schools, which is quite poor.

Comment: style wise i'd prefer the first, as the function does one simple thing and can be more easily reused

Comment: Why are you using a `function` at all? It's pretty useless unless it is executed multiple time. If you *do* call it multiple times, you'll quickly see how they are different.

Comment: In the first example, the function is [pure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function), while the one in the second example has [side-effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)).

Comment: All,

Thanks  for the explanations guys, but can anyone please give me a situation where "this code" is more suitable than "that code" and vice versa?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Given the code you described,

```
function myFunction() { 
  return "Hello World"
}
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = myFunction();
```

If `myFunction()` were executed somewhere else (say attached to a button), it would simply return the string "Hello World".

```
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World!";
}
myFunction();
```

When `myFunction()` is executed as described above, it would change the HTML of an element with the `id="demo"`.

The complete set of code, including the fourth line of each would do the same thing, but the function inside each would provide completely different functionality.

Answer (score 0):

They produce the same result however the first one gets the string value from the function call whereas the second assigns the value directly from within the function.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is well known for multitude of ways to accomplish same result.
Based on your code snippets it's very subjective to say which is more practical. Both of them are fairly simple, just to proof the concept (you don't have function that only returns string).

To answer your comment lets try to imagine more practical situation.

```
var isAuth = true; // lets imagine this comes as result of non trivial authentication process
function customGreeting(isAuthenticated) { 
    return isAuthenticated ? "Hello, welcome back" : "Please Sign in to continue";
}
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = customGreeting(isAuth);
```

Above code uses approach from first snippet. Some might say that it more 'elegant' than using second approach (bellow).

```
var isAuth = true; // lets imagine this comes as result of non trivial authentication process
function customGreeting(isAuthenticated) {
    if(isAuthenticated){
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello, welcome back";
    }else{
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Please Sign in to continue";
    }
}
customGreeting();
```

If we set functional programming approach aside (with is out of scope for this discussion) it's very hard to argue which approach is better.

Comment: I kind of get the explaination here but I have not ventured to codes with variables with the "true" value. I am assuming that I would run into this when I get in forms and inputs? But thanks @oKonyk !

Comment: @patric when you get more exposure to coding, you'll see that it we are dealing a lot with all sorts of conditions. We check `if` this it `true` do `that`, `if` not do `something else` :) In my example `var isAuth = true;` is coming from  imaginary `authentication` service (which implementation is not trivial:). Values can come from forms, backend requests etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm looking forward to get more exposure.